# Using Predicate in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios7, predicate

I'm working through the tutorial here (learning Swift) for my first app:
http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

I'm stuck on this part (Objective-C code):

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c]         %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Can anyone advise how to create an equivalent for NSPredicate in Swift?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

This is really just a syntax switch. OK, so we have this method call:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
```

In Swift, constructors skip the "blahWith…" part and just use the class name as a function and then go straight to the arguments, so `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: …]` would become `NSPredicate(format: …)`. (For another example, `[NSArray arrayWithObject: …]` would become `NSArray(object: …)`. This is a regular pattern in Swift.)

So now we just need to pass the arguments to the constructor. In Objective-C, NSString literals look like `@""`, but in Swift we just use quotation marks for strings. So that gives us:

```
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", searchText)
```

And in fact that is exactly what we need here.

(Incidentally, you'll notice some of the other answers instead use a format string like `"name contains[c] \(searchText)"`. That is not correct. That uses string interpolation, which is different from predicate formatting and will generally not work for this.)

Comment: To address the second line of your method, you might use the predicate as: `searchResults = recipes.filter { resultPredicate.evaluateWithObject($0) }`

Answer (score 48):

Working with predicate for pretty long time. Here is my conclusion (SWIFT)

```
//Customizable! (for me was just important if at least one)
request.fetchLimit = 1


//IF IS EQUAL

//1 OBJECT
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", txtFieldName.text)

//ARRAY
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@ AND nickName = %@", argumentArray: [name, nickname])


// IF CONTAINS

//1 OBJECT
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", txtFieldName.text)

//ARRAY
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@ AND nickName contains[c] %@", argumentArray: [name, nickname])
```

Comment: What's equal with `LIKE 'a%z'` ?

Comment: @Jiří Zahálka What is request hear means?

Answer (score 28):

Example how to use in swift 2.0

```
let dataSource = [
    "Domain CheckService",
    "IMEI check",
    "Compliant about service provider",
    "Compliant about TRA",
    "Enquires",
    "Suggestion",
    "SMS Spam",
    "Poor Coverage",
    "Help Salim"
]
let searchString = "Enq"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains %@", searchString)
let searchDataSource = dataSource.filter { predicate.evaluateWithObject($0) }
```

You will get (playground)

[image]

Comment: What if... If i have a array of dictionaries? How do i parse to get the data?

Comment: @RevathyDurairajan you need SELF.yourkeyname for filtering array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 12):

You can use filters available in swift to filter content from an array instead of using a predicate like in Objective-C.

An example in Swift 4.0 is as follows:

```
var stringArray = ["foundation","coredata","coregraphics"]
stringArray = stringArray.filter { $0.contains("core") }
```

In the above example, since each element in the array is a string you can use the `contains` method to filter the array.

If the array contains custom objects, then the properties of that object can be used to filter the elements similarly.

Answer (score 6):

Use The Below code:

```
 func filterContentForSearchText(searchText:NSString, scopes scope:NSString)
{
    //var searchText = ""

    var resultPredicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c]\(searchText)", nil)

    //var recipes : NSArray = NSArray()

    var searchResults = recipes.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
}
```

Comment: For some reason writing it like that didn't work for me however doing  let myPredicateString = "name contains[c]\(searchText)" and then doing var resultPredicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format:myPredicateString) did

Answer (score 5):

I think this would be a better way to do it in Swift:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText:NSString, scope:NSString)
{
   searchResults = recipes.filter { name.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil  }
}
```

Comment: This is more idiomatic if you're filtering a `Sequence`, but there are cases where you will need a `NSPredicate`, like when dealing with `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Answer (score 1):

**In swift 2.2**

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String) {
    var resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c]         %@", searchText)
    searchResults = (recipes as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
}
```

**In swift 3.0**

```
func filterContent(forSearchText searchText: String, scope: String) {
        var resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c]         %@", searchText)
        searchResults = recipes.filtered(using: resultPredicate)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

// change "name" and "value" according to your array data.

// Change "yourDataArrayName" name accroding to your array(NSArray).

```
    let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name contains[c] %@", "value")

    if let sortedDta = yourDataArrayName.filtered(using: resultPredicate) as? NSArray {

 //enter code here.

        print(sortedDta)
    }
```