# How can I update data using Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

My problem is that I can easily add and delete data but when I am trying to update data in Tableview did select method, when I update the last row it works fine but when I am trying to update any other row it will set the value to below row data.  If any one have an answer for that then please help me for that.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    var people = [Person]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()

        do {
            let people = try PersistenceServce.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            self.people = people
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } catch {}
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func onPlusTapped() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Person", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Name"
        }
        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Age"
            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        }
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Post", style: .default) { (_) in
            let name = alert.textFields!.first!.text!
            let age = alert.textFields!.last!.text!
            let person = Person(context: PersistenceServce.context)
            person.name = name
            person.age = Int16(age)!
            PersistenceServce.saveContext()
            self.people.append(person)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return people.count

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = people[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(people[indexPath.row].age)
        return cell

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let person = people[indexPath.row]
        if editingStyle == .delete  {
            PersistenceServce.context.delete(person)
            PersistenceServce.saveContext()
            people.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Update Person", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.text = self.people[indexPath.row].name
        }
        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.text = String(self.people[indexPath.row].age)
            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        }
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .default) { (_) in

        let name = alert.textFields!.first!.text!
        let age = alert.textFields!.last!.text!
            print(self.people)


            PersistenceServce.context.delete(self.people[indexPath.row])
            print(self.people)

            let person = Person(context: PersistenceServce.context)
            person.name = name
            person.age = Int16(age)!
            self.people.append(person)
            self.people.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            print(self.people)
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            PersistenceServce.saveContext()

        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you update a CoreData entry that has already been saved in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345189/how-do-you-update-a-coredata-entry-that-has-already-been-saved-in-swift)

Comment: No it's not duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overdoing it, no need to delete and insert a new Person object every time a change is done. Just update the attribute on the object, Core Data will take care of the rest since it already manages the object.

Something like

```
let selectedPerson = self.people[indexPath.row]
selectedPerson.name = ...
selectedPerson.age = ...
```

And then you might have to call reloadData()/reloadRows(...) on the table view